# Get lasting permission to write to a specific directory with the new Sandbox requirements

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sandbox, osx-mountain-lion

I need a way to get & keep permission to write to a specific directory in OS X. How can that be done while abiding with the new Sandbox requirements?

Answer (score 0):

The recipe:

1. Ask the user to select the directory - use a standard open dialog limited to directory selection. Apart from a few special directories (music, pictures etc.) there is no way to gain access apart from asking the user.
2. Create a security-scoped bookmark using the URL returned by the standard open dialog, just search the Apple docs for "security-scoped bookmark".
3. Persist that bookmark, either in user preferences or in the Application Support folder for your app.
4. On application launch, or before you need access, read in the saved bookmark and activate - you'll find out how to do this in the Apple docs as above.